# Update pyspark's dataframe column

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to create a new dataframe from an older one modifying the  element that appears in it. I have a dataframe like this:

```
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
| A     |            B       |                   C|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 224.39|[2533695.47884,25...|[2.53311343446655...|
| 398.56|[2551303.18964,25...|[6740638.70550121...|
|1445.59|[2530998.06972,25...|[7839490.11546087...|
```

In columns B and C there are lists of elements (approx. 100 in each row of each column). I would like to create a new dataframe from this one selecting only, for instance, 5 elements in the column C for each row. It would be something like this:

```
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
| A     |            B       |                   C|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 224.39|[2533695.47884,25...|[1,2,3,4,5]         |
| 398.56|[2551303.18964,25...|[1,2,3,4,5]         |
|1445.59|[2530998.06972,25...|[1,2,3,4,5]         |
```

So far I've only managed to extract in a new dataframe the column C and I tried to use `foreach(lambda x: x[0:5])`, but the dataframe after this foreach is a NoneType element and it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a way to do this. Using [VectorSlicer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorslicer) is quite simple to select features from PCA.